# Repaint won't happen until the for loop has escaped, with only two frames

Tags: java, animation, jcomponent

I'm trying to do some basic Java, and I've got my frame with a shape in it. It's using a JComponent class to draw the shape, with the animation being triggered on a button click at the top.

the component code is just this added to the jpanel

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    Dimension dim = getSize();      
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(margin, 150, 100, 100);  
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

The animation is just done inside a for loop, that just edits the left margin so that the circle moves to the right;

```
int getMarg = cc.getMargin();
            for(int i = 1;i < 20;i++){  
                getMarg = cc.getMargin();
                cc.setMargin(getMarg + 1);              
                reValidate();
                System.out.println(i);
```

But it doesn't seem to move until the end of the loop, moving 20 pixels at a time. I previously had a sleep function but it seemed pointless when it wouldn't animate.

Any insight? Cheers.

The whole code for anyone interested, messy and largely just to get the styling:

```
class Main extends JFrame{

public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button1 = new JButton("Move Right");

CreateComps cc = new CreateComps();

Main(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initUI();
}

void initUI(){
    setSize(800,800);
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel topBar = new JPanel();
    topBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,30));
    topBar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800,30));
    topBar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    topBar.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    topBar.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    container.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,500));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,500));
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(cc, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(topBar);
    add(container);
    container.add(panel);

    Listener listen = new Listener();
    button1.addActionListener(listen);

    setVisible(true);
}

public void reValidate(){
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
}

class Listener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Listening..");
        if(e.getSource().equals(button1)){
            int getMarg = cc.getMargin();
            for(int i = 1;i < 20;i++){  
                getMarg = cc.getMargin();
                cc.setMargin(getMarg + 1);              
                reValidate();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }                       
    }   
}



}

class CreateComps extends JComponent{

int margin = 10;        
public void setMargin(int marg){
    margin = marg;
}   
public int getMargin(){
    return margin;
}   
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(new Dimension(200,200));
}   
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize(){
    return new Dimension(new Dimension(200,200));
}   
@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
    return new Dimension(new Dimension(200,200));
}   
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    Dimension dim = getSize();      
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(margin, 150, 100, 100);  
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without pauses, you're stacking calls to `revalidate` and will see nothing else than the result of the last call.

The sleep function you previously had, probably was called on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which is not good at all, since you're blocking the entire event dispatching and GUI updates.

Consider either using `sleep` calls on another `Thread` :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Listening..");
    if (e.getSource().equals(button1)) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int getMarg = cc.getMargin();
                for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                    getMarg = cc.getMargin();
                    cc.setMargin(getMarg + 1);
                    reValidate();
                    System.out.println(i);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                    }

                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

}
```

Or you may also simply use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which is great for this job.

Comment: While this does illuminate the core of the problem (tight loop/sleeping on the EDT), I cannot upvote an answer that such a large amount of bad practices in such a small piece of code. For once, almost every class in Swing has `Swing is not thread safe`. Don't call `getMargin()` and `setMargin()` etc. from non-EDT threads. And why would you create an entire new thread when you have the convenient Swing `Timer` class that will run your `Runnable` on the EDT directly without the need for sleeps?